# How to pass optional params in url in django python

Tags: python, django

i have 2 type of URL `crud/app` and other is `crud/app/2` here you can see id can be optional, so how to apply this type of URL pattern, here i have added my code,

```
app_name = 'crud'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/<:id>',views.add, name='add'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urls.py

```py
app_name = 'crud'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('add',views.add, name='add_empty'),
    path('add/<int:id>',views.add, name='add_id'),
]
```

views.py

```py
def add(request, id=None):

    # if id was provided
    if id:
        [...]
    else:
        [...]
```

**But** you shouldn't overwrite function names (`id`).